# Is it possible to use forms as fields in other forms?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a form that I've created in Django:

```
class someForm(forms.Form):...
```

that takes in a variable, `someVariable`, in its init function:

```
def __init__(self, someVariable, *args, **kwargs):
```

Is it possible for me to use someForm as a field in another form like so?:

```
class someOtherForm(forms.Form):
    sf = someForm(someVariable=self.someVariable)
...
    def __init__(self, someVariable, *args, **kwargs)
    self.someVariable = someVariable
```

Comment: No, forms and form fields aren't interchangeable. You'll need to explain what your goal is in trying to copy one form to another. If the goal is to make a form `someOtherForm` which shares fields with `someForm`, then the best way is using form inheritance (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be extending the original form like so:

```
def someForm(forms.Form):
    someVariable = ...
    ...
    def __init__(self, someVariable, *args, **kwargs):
        self.someVariable = someVariable

def someOtherForm(someForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, someVariable, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeOtherForm, self).__init__(someVariable, *args, **kwargs)
```